FluentValidation with OR?
I was looking at this link trying to figure out how to quickly and easily do an OR but so far the path to discovery has taken me down a LONG road to excessive code for what is and should be a very simple task that has eluded me.
From my validator I was hoping to do something simple like this:
public class BookingEquipmentModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BookingEquipmentModel> // AKA ShipmentEquipmentModelValidator
{
    public BookingEquipmentModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(be => be.BookingId).GreaterThan(0);
        RuleFor(be => be.BookingSlotId).GreaterThan(0);
        RuleFor(be => be.GeneralVentSetting).MaximumLength(50);
        RuleFor(be => be.Comments).MaximumLength(254);
        RuleFor(be => be.SealNumber).MaximumLength(15);
        When(be => be.EquipmentId > 0, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(be => be.ActualEquipmentTypeId).Equals(be => be.FirstRequestedEquipmentTypeId).Or
                .Equals(be => be.SecondRequestedEquipmentTypeId).WithMessage("No Match on either Req1 or Req2");
        });
        

.Or is not valid syntax, but I can't seem to make any approach work.  The objective:

If Equipment is provided (EquipmentId > 0), then the Equipment Type (ActualEquipmentTypeId) must match EITHER Request1 Equipment Type (FirstRequestedEquipmentTypeId) OR Request2 Equipment Type (SecondRequestedEquipmentTypeId).
If NEITHER Equipment Types match to Actual, then a validation error should be returned.

All the properties are contained within the BookingEquipmentModel.
I tried this approach, but
        When(be => be.EquipmentId is > 0, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(be => be.ActualEquipmentTypeId != be.SecondRequestedEquipmentTypeId && be.ActualEquipmentTypeId != be.FirstRequestedEquipmentTypeId).Equals(true);
        });

I'm hoping I'm just blind to something very simple, but really don't know.

I was able to come up with a reasonably good solution:
        When(be => be.EquipmentId > 0, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(be => be).Must(IsMatchingEquipment);
        });

...
    private bool IsMatchingEquipment(BookingEquipmentModel b)
    {
        if (b.ActualEquipmentTypeId is > 0)
        {
            return (b.ActualEquipmentTypeId == b.FirstRequestedEquipmentTypeId || b.ActualEquipmentTypeId == b.SecondRequestedEquipmentTypeId);
        }

        // always return true if no equipment is specified
        return true;
    }

